# Calculating a sector from a number of points

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

I have a single center point. Also, there is a number of additional points (in fact they are geographic coordinates, but it doesn't matter much in this case), for which I can calculate a direction. I need to find a smallest sector that will contain all of the points inside. Basically, it is this:[image]

How do I approach the problem? Yeah, I know its basic math, but I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Sector's area will be determined by two factors Angle of the sector and radius of the sector. Now from the points given how do you minimize both of them?

Comment: Radius is easy - it is simply the farthest point in the sector. Calculating angles is what i need help with =)

Comment: shift the coordinates with your center being origin and represent the new coordinates in polar coordinates. Now maximum difference between two angles will be your angle of the sector

Comment: Are you planning on writing a code?